# How to use PowerShell in a batch file, not script, to rename multiple files in a folder & all subfolders?

Tags: powershell, batch-processing

This batch file *.bat, not script ~ does just that, just for the folder the batch file is in, but how about all the subfolders under it?

This is what I have tried:

```
powershell -C "gci | ForEach-Object % {rni $_.Name ($_.Name -replace '15June', '01July ')}"
```

Comment: Not tested, but `gci -Recursive`, is what you probably need

Comment: The code you posted can't possibly work, because `ForEach-Object %` is not valid syntax, so you should be getting a syntax error for each file.

Answer (score 1):

`Rename-Item` accepts pipeline input, so you don't need `ForEach-Object` there. For including subfolders add the parameter `-Recurse` to `Get-ChildItem`.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '15June', '01July'}
```

From a batch file you should be able to run the statement like this:

```
powershell.exe -Command "Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '15June', '01July'}"
```

or (if you want to use aliases, which is not recommended for scripting):

```
powershell.exe -c "ls -r | ren -n {$_.Name -replace '15June', '01July'}"
```

Comment: There is no change to the sub folder's files with -Recurse added...

powershell -C "gci -Recurse | ForEach-Object % {rni $_.Name ($_.Name -replace '15June', '01July')}"

This does not work as well..
powershell -C "gci -Recurse | Rename % {$_.Name ($_.Name -replace '15June', '01July')}"

Comment: @Jevv Please run the *EXACT STATEMENT* from my answer in a PowerShell console. Do not add anything. Do not leave anything out. Does that work? If not, please update your question with the output of `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` (at least sample output showing the files that should've been renamed, but weren't).

Comment: I wanted to run it from a .bat file like the example since when I try to run from the console, I get an error "scripts not allowed on this system" Can't it be made to run from a *.bat file instead? Adding Powershell -C in front of Get-ChildItem -Recurse does not run... Thanks

Comment: Ok Sir, pasted into the PS console and get this message:                  Rename-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '$_.Name -replace ''15June', '01July''.
At line:1 char:26
+ Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item {$_.Name -replace '15June', '01July'}
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Rename-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Comment: *\*slaps self\** Sorry, that was my mistake actually. The scriptblock must be passed as a named parameter here (`Rename-Item -NewName {...}`). Please try again with the updated code from my answer. Again, if it doesn't work, update your question with the command output. We'll get to moving the code to batch after making sure that the PowerShell side works.

Comment: Ah, forgot about adding -C or -Command for the batch..Thanks Ansgar! Great work, very professional...That batch works just as I requested.